# Fixed div jumps on smartphones

Tags: html, css, svg

This problem occurs only on smartphones. I'm testing with an iPhone 6 right now. As soon as I scroll down, the top address bar of the browser disappears - therefore the black SVG jumps that is positioned in a fixed div is moving/jumping. Very annoying behaviour. I searched for a solution for hours...

Open the following url (testing-website) on your smartphone and see what happens:
https://www.webagentur-friedli.ch/morph17/aargau/webdesign.html

How can I fix this?

```css
.morph-wrap {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 pointer-events: none;
 z-index: 0
}
.morph {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 flex: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="morph-wrap">
    <svg class="morph" width="1400" height="770" viewBox="0 0 1400 770">
          <path d="M 262.9,252.2 C 210.1,338.2 212.6,487.6 288.8,553.9 372.2,626.5 511.2,517.8 620.3,536.3 750.6,558.4 860.3,723 987.3,686.5 1089,657.3 1168,534.7 1173,429.2 1178,313.7 1096,189.1 995.1,130.7 852.1,47.07 658.8,78.95 498.1,119.2 410.7,141.1 322.6,154.8 262.9,252.2 Z"/>
        </svg>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p>
```

Comment: looks ok on android

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for making me aware about this - it's my first question on stackoverflow! Find code snippet in question now. I did not add it first because you can't find failure in desktop browsers - it's only on smartphones...

Comment: @LorDex: I see the described issue on Chrome for Android. It's hard to notice if you just scroll quickly, but the bar at the top is shown or hidden by scrolling the page, and the `morph` classed svg gets recentered on the new page size each time.

Comment: Have you tried setting `height` to `device-height`?

Comment: @3D1T0R device-height is related to a media-query, no? Please tell me what you mean?